# What is the correct use of an onClick method in fragments to open new activities?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-button

Re-Edit: For those interested the method for onClick was resolved below. Turns out you cannot create separate classes for controls so the button controls need to be inside the current active class.

The issue: In my fragment I have included several controls, one of which is a button that should open a new activity. When clicking the button I get the following crash...

**This is the LogCat error when clicking the button in my current active Fragment**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.paymentdemo, PID: 14352
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button_next_trans'
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:424)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:381)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

**This is the fragment hosting the controls**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/transaction_header"
        style="?textGroupheader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/group_header"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- Spinner displays accounts available using SpinnerActivity -->
    <include
        layout="@layout/fragment_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- Radio checks on or off. Still need to link selected as fragments for button on click behaviour -->
    <include
        layout="@layout/fragment_radio"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- Button will take selected radio and open related activity, for now we just go to MainActivity -->
    <include
        layout="@layout/fragment_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**The button control code**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ButtonActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_next_trans"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@drawable/action_button"
        android:paddingStart="24dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:onClick="goToPayments"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**The button activity**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;


public class ButtonActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_button);
    }

    public void goToPayments(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

I'm not experienced so my implementation may be a bit rusty. If you have any advice on how to properly implement a button onClick method I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the button and View for framgment
Like this

```
 Button button;
 public View myView;
```

Then in onCreate initialize like this

```
 myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_button,container,false);
 button = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.button_next_trans);
```

then create method like this this,

```
  public void payments(){
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class)
           startActivity(i);
           }
        }
   }
```

And at end of onCreate() method return view.

```
 return myView;
```

And call payments(); in onCreate

Comment: There seems to be some syntax errors here but I've tried this and it seems to throw the same error.

Comment: While i think the method works, it doesn't seem to work in this context. There may be an issue with the way it is used in the Fragment. Separately in a new app this works.

Comment: No stress, you have been very helpful, as it stands the code for fragments is working with a few tweaks to the syntax. I am still getting some errors on clicking the button but I have a feeling it has to do with the way it is nested within the fragment it is being included into. I'm marking this as resolved as it answers my initial question. I will still need to work on the reason for the method not working within the fragment it is housed in.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ButtonActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_button);

    Button btnPay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_next_trans);
    btnPay.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void goToPayments(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_next_trans:
            goToPayments();
            break;      
    }
  }
}}
```

Remove below line from xml

```
android:onClick="goToPayments"
```

Comment: I get "goToPayment(View) in ButtonActivity cannot be applied to ()" when I remove View view form the goToPayments method it clears this error but doesn't compile